# How accessibility affect font sizes in iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, fonts, accessibility

I am a designer trying to design my typography for mobile apps.
I have a question regarding how "accessibility" will affect the font sizes.

As in Android, you can change the font size scale from tiny to huge.
By default it is "Small".

As I play around with the font size, it seems to me that some font sizes within an app will change and some will not. How can I tell which font will be affected by accessibility and which will not?

Similar to iOS as well, how well accessibility affect the font sizes?

Answer (score 3):

You can use dp for fixed pixel font sizes or sp for dynamic font sizes in Android.
E.g.:

```
android:textSize="26sp"
```

or

```
android:textSize="26dp"
```

User preferences will affect the first one. The second one not.

[A good overview](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-basic-font-sizes--mobile-11194)

Comment: Which is why you should use the first in almost all cases.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand this correctly, "dp" units will only affect padding, margins for different viewports but not for typography? How about iOS? How does font sizes work? I played with the accessibility settings and it seems that some apps will change the  font size some wont?

Answer (score 3):

To understand how the font sizes work in iOS, take a look at the `WWDC 2017 : Building Apps with Dynamic Type` video whose content is perfectly summarized [here](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html).

The first two sections (`Text styles` and `Custom fonts`) should provide you important information about the connection between accessibility and the font sizes.

Everything is well explained to get a full understanding of how the text styles, the font sizes and the custom fonts must be used to have the expected response in iOS accessibility.