# Font Size in Android Virtual Devices

Tags: android, fonts, android-virtual-device

I am struggling with the selection of font sizes in my Android app. I have a number of real devices, different sizes, different OS versions, different manufacturers, phones and tablets.

The text looks good on all of those devices.

However, when I run the app in the emulator, the fonts are often too large. Obviously, this has to do with the display size and resolution settings for my virtual devices. So I have been toying around a bit with different instructions I could find on the web including a virtual device repository and the Samsung skins. Still, I don't seem to get a good match between real and virtual devices. As an example, the Nexus 5 virtual device preconfigured shows the fonts are monstrous. Font sizes I use are between 10sp for small text and 26sp for very large headers.

I could now configure the emulator such that my app looks great but then I really can't be sure what users will see on their real hardware. What is the right approach for gaining enough confidence that my app looks good in the real world?

Comment: You can use dp instead of sp.
Further information: [SO-Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712864/how-accessibility-affect-font-sizes-in-ios-and-android/34713064#34713064)

Comment: Understand. But I would like the user to be able to fine-tune the sizes to his/her vision. It would be nice if I can count on the "default" setting not producing giant fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `sp` as unit for font sizes, the fonts are scaled according to your user's preferences. If you don't want to allow your fonts to be scaled you should use `dp` as unit for font sizes.

But I wouldn't recommend doing this because this limits accessibility for users with impaired eyesight.

Comment: Yes, understand. I can accept that if the user chooses the maximum font size the text might be a bit out of proportion. That user will probably see that also in other apps. But what worries me here is that the user settings in those virtual devices are untouched, and the "default" appearance is way too large. I definitely prefer using sp, and the appearance should be OK unless the user uses extreme text sizes.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for are virtual devices which I can rely on that behave like their physical counterparts, so I can see what the users see without having to invest 10,000EUR on test devices.

Comment: I'll accept the answer now though it was not exactly what I was looking for - it might still be useful for others. There may indeed be no alternative to getting a set of real devices to test the layout. In exceptional situations such as image buttons using dp might be a feasible option, especially if the font is not too small to begin with.